# NodeJS Determine if drive is removable

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way using Node JS, via `fs.stat()` or otherwise to determine if a given directory and/or drive is removable (like a USB drive)?

I'm looking for a cross-platform method (or at least, one method that works for Windows, one for Mac and I can make my own cross-platform function).

Comment: have you tried is `stats.isBlockDevice()` ?

Comment: isBlockDevice() seems to return false for both normal disk drives and removeable disk drives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a small cross-platform module (works in OS X, Windows and GNU/Linux) called [drivelist](https://github.com/resin-io-modules/drivelist) that lists the connected drives in your computer. The resulting drives contain a `system` property that determines if the drive is removable or not, for example, on Windows:

```
[
    {
        device: '\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0',
        description: 'WDC WD10JPVX-75JC3T0',
        size: '1000 GB'
        mountpoint: 'C:',
        system: true
    },
    {
        device: '\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE1',
        description: 'Generic STORAGE DEVICE USB Device',
        size: '15 GB'
        mountpoint: 'D:',
        system: false
    }
]
```

You can filter the list by the one you're interested in, and inspect the `system` property:

```
var drivelist = require('drivelist');

drivelist.list(function(error, disks) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var drive = drives.find(function(drive) {
    return drive.mountpoint === 'C:';
  });

  if (drive.system) {
    console.log('C: is not removable!');
  }
});
```

We use various mechanisms to determine if a drive is removable, feel free to take a closer look on the platform you that you're most interested in!

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar to what you are asking for but it's a linux specific implementation.  In the particular distribution of linux I'm using (Ubunut 12.04), all removeable drives are mounted in /media, so I just check to see if the drive is mounted there.  If it is, then I know it's removeable.

I know this isn't using some sort of Node utility like the fs object so it's not going to be platform independent.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this could work for the Linux and possible Mac side. Unfortunately, I need it to work for the Windows side as well.

Comment: You could write a small C++ program and then call that from node using exec.  The C++ program could use the following windows library call to figure out exactly what you are looking for:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364939(v=vs.85).aspx